# Quartus Prime Qsys HPS (Hard Processor System) error

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, quartus, system-on-chip

I'm trying to generate a system including HPS (Hard Processor System) of the Cyclone V SoC in Quartus Prime Qsys. At the "Generate HDL" stage I got the following errors. I'm not expecting all the error codes to be analyzed, but I put them here because someone might have ecnountered similar errors and solved them.

I'm using Quartus Prime 17.0 standard edition on Windows 10. I've tried the Quartus Prime versions 13.1, 15.1 and 16.0; still same errors. I tried different configurations on Qsys (connecting HPS to different hardware units, configuring the HPS in a different way); still got the same errors. Tried to create project in different levels of folders; didn't help. I would be glad if anyone has an opinion about this.

P.S: I know this isn't the exact community of Stack Exchange to ask this question but the possibility of someone from this community to encounter similar errors is high.

```
Error: border: Error during execution of script generate_hps_sdram.tcl: add_parameter: string not allowed for EParameterType, must be in {[INTEGER, NATURAL, POSITIVE, BOOLEAN, STD_LOGIC, STD_LOGIC_VECTOR, STRING, STRING_LIST, INTEGER_LIST, LONG, FLOAT]}
Error: border: Error during execution of script generate_hps_sdram.tcl: add_parameter AC_ROM_MR0   : null
Error: border: Error during execution of script generate_hps_sdram.tcl: set_parameter_property: No parameter AC_ROM_MR0
Error: border: Error during execution of script generate_hps_sdram.tcl: Could not load altera_mem_if_hps_emif
Error: border: Execution of script generate_hps_sdram.tcl failed
Error: border: 2017.05.20.17:09:19 Error: add_parameter: string not allowed for EParameterType, must be in {[INTEGER, NATURAL, POSITIVE, BOOLEAN, STD_LOGIC, STD_LOGIC_VECTOR, STRING, STRING_LIST, INTEGER_LIST, LONG, FLOAT]}
Error: border: 2017.05.20.17:09:19 Error: add_parameter AC_ROM_MR0   : null
Error: border: 2017.05.20.17:09:19 Error: set_parameter_property: No parameter AC_ROM_MR0
Error: border: Error during execution of script generate_hps_sdram.tcl: Could not load altera_mem_if_hps_emif
Error: border: Execution of script generate_hps_sdram.tcl failed
Error: border: 2017.05.22.01:36:18 Info:
Error: border: ********************************************************************************************************************
Error: border: 
Error: border: Use qsys-generate for a simpler command-line interface for generating IP.
Error: border: 
Error: border: Run ip-generate with switch --remove-qsys-generate-warning to prevent this notice from appearing in subsequent runs.
Error: border: 
Error: border: ********************************************************************************************************************
Error: border: 2017.05.22.01:36:22 Error: add_parameter: string not allowed for EParameterType, must be in {[INTEGER, NATURAL, POSITIVE, BOOLEAN, STD_LOGIC, STD_LOGIC_VECTOR, STRING, STRING_LIST, INTEGER_LIST, LONG, FLOAT]}
Error: border: 2017.05.22.01:36:22 Error: add_parameter AC_ROM_MR0   : null
Error: border: 2017.05.22.01:36:22 Error: set_parameter_property: No parameter AC_ROM_MR0
Error: border: while executing
Error: border: "set_parameter_property AC_ROM_MR0 DERIVED true"
Error: border: (procedure "_create_derived_mode_register_parameters" line 11)
Error: border: invoked from within
Error: border: "_create_derived_mode_register_parameters"
Error: border: invoked from within
Error: border: "alt_mem_if::gui::common_ddr_mem_model::create_parameters"
Error: border: (file "common_hps_emif.tcl" line 42)
Error: border: (file line 42)
Error: border: invoked from within
Error: border: "source common_hps_emif.tcl"
Error: border: (file "C:/intelfpga/17.0/ip/altera/alt_mem_if/alt_mem_if_interfaces/alt_mem_if_hps_emif/altera_mem_if_hps_emif_hw.tcl" line 22)
Error: border: 2017.05.20.17:09:19 Error: Could not load altera_mem_if_hps_emif
Error: border: add_fileset_file: No such file C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/alt7307_6443717614927326703.dir/0002_border_gen/hps_sdram.v while executing "add_fileset_file [file join $dest_subdir $dest_filename] $file_type PATH [file join $src_fulldir $filename]" ("if" then script line 54) invoked from within...
```

Comment: Submit it to Intel/Altera.

Comment: Second line from the bottom: `C:/altera/13.1/ip/...` - Do you have more than one version of Quartus installed?

Comment: In the system environment variables, what are the values of `QSYS_ROOTDIR` and `QUARTUS_ROOTDIR`?

Comment: @TomCarpenter It was from the 13.1 version I mistakenly put that. The edit that I made now is from 17.0. I use just one version at a time. The errors are almost the same though. The variables are `QSYS_ROOTDIR C:\intelFPGA\17.0\quartus\sopc_builder\bin` and `QUARTUS_ROOTDIR C:\intelFPGA\17.0\quartus` . I think they are correct I checked them from an Altera documentation. I suspect the errors have something to do with the last Win 10 update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that problem is the default language of Windows 10. I changed it into English(United States) (`Start Menu->Settings->Time & language`) and the errors are gone.

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan had a great explanation as to what is happening [at this site](https://forum.rocketboards.org/t/de10-nano-manual-instructions-fail-to-compile-ghrd-on-ubuntu-solved/1282/6).

solution: sudo apt-get install make